JS structuredClone: not truly deep copy?
Today, while investigating a bug in our app, I witnessed a very surprising behavior in JavaScript's structuredClone.
This method promises to create a deep clone of a given value. This was previously achieved using the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) technique, and on paper structuredClone appears to be a superset per se of this technique, yielding the same result, while also supporting things like Dates and circular references.
However, today I learned that if you use structuredClone to clone an object containing reference type variables pointing to the same reference, these references will be kept, as opposed to creating new values with different references.
Here is a toy example to demonstrate this behavior:
const someSharedArray = ['foo', 'bar']

const myObj = {
  field1: someSharedArray,
  field2: someSharedArray,
  field3: someSharedArray,
}

const myObjCloned = structuredClone(myObj)

console.log(myObjCloned)
/**
{
    "field1": ["foo", "bar"],
    "field2": ["foo", "bar"],
    "field3": ["foo", "bar"],
}
**/

myObjCloned.field2[1] = 'baz'

// At this point:
// Expected: only `field2`'s value should change, because `myObjCloned` was deeply cloned.
// Actual: all fields' values change, because they all still point to `someSharedArray`

console.log(myObjCloned)
/**
{
    "field1": ["foo", "baz"],
    "field2": ["foo", "baz"],
    "field3": ["foo", "baz"],
}
**/

This is a very surprising behavior of structuredClone, because:

It claims to perform deep cloning
This behavior doesn't happen when using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))


If you had done myObj.field2[1] = 'baz' instead, you would have the exact same behavior in myObj already. So why should a clone behave any different, than the original?

Does it also reflect to myObj? If yes: that'd be surprising. If not: arguably myObjCloned behaves exactly as myObj would.

Surprising but knowing that makes structuredClone even better

myObjCloned IS deep cloned. As is the array. The structure is preserved as-is and there are no links from someSharedArray to the clone. All the requirements for deep cloning are fulfilled. You seem to expect that the shared array would suddenly become multiple arrays but I don't think it's a reasonable expectation.

@deceze No, the original object myObj is not affected, only the clone.

Also, what is the question here? Do you want to use structuredClone but also de-structure it to make a separate clone for shared objects?

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) has always been an ugly hack IMO, which has always had several asterisks attached to it, like not being able to "clone" certain types or causing shared array references to arguably break. structuredClone is the much more faithful cloning mechanism. You've just been relying on side effects of the JSON workaround so far.

Also, if you don't want shared objects - why is the solution you're reaching for to "fix" this when cloning? Why do you not prevent this at the source of the cloning?

@VLAZ The reasons this was surprising to me, as mentioned in the thread, are:

This is a deviation from the resulting value of using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)),
I did not expect shared references to be kept in the clone, even if a new shared reference is created.


JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) isn't really "cloning" anyway. So, saying an actual cloning algorithm works different should yield zero surprise. It recreates the data by passing it through an intermediary representation. An intermediary representation which is more limited than the original. Of course it produces copies that aren't like the original. Just try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a: undefined, b: 1})) and you'll immediately find it's not cloning.

Again, though: what is being asked here?

@VLAZ I guess the questions are: 1. Does structuredClone truly deep clone? 2. Is structuredClone supposed to yield the same output as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) given the same (JSON-supported) input?
And I guess the answers are: 1: yes, just not in the way I thought, and 2. Not necessarily.


simply cannot be a "yes" ever. Consider foo = {}; bar = {}; foo.bar = bar; bar.foo = foo - two objects with a circular reference between them. JSON can't really represent that. Serialising to JSON would throw an error. Yet, it's a perfectly valid data. It does work in JS. You can get a second copy of it via cloning. I don't find it reasonable to claim it's not possible to clone this, or that cloning the circular reference should produce some different data.


Put another way: did structuredClone ever claim to behave the same as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)? Where did Javascript ever endorse JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) officially as the canonical way to clone objects?


not truly deep copy?

It is a deep copy.
A proper deep copy should adhere to a few conditions:

It should map every distinct object in the original to exactly one distinct object in the result: a 1-to-1 mapping. This is also the guiding principle that ensures that circular references are supported.

If two distinct properties have identical values (Object.is(a, b) === true), then these properties in the deep clone should also be identical to each other.


In your example input there are two distinct objects: one array, and one (top-level) complex object. Furthermore, the result of Object.is(myObj.field1, myObj.field2) is true.
What you get with structuredClone in your example adheres to this. Notibly, Object.is(myObjCloned.field1, myObjCloned.field2) is true.
What you expected to get (and what JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) returns) violates this principle: three distinct arrays would be created, which means the same array has been copied more than once, and there is no 1-to-1 mapping anymore. The previously mentioned Object.is expression evaluates to false.
Another scenario
Let's take an input with a back reference:
const root = {};
root.arr = [root, root, root];

Here we have one object and one array. That latter holds three references to the first object. Also here we expect these three references to one object to result in another trio of references, each referencing the one-and-only clone-parent object. This is the same principle as what happens in your example, just that the shared reference happens to be a parent object.

OP even mentioned this themselves: "structuredClone appears to be a superset [of this technique], while also supporting things like […] circular references."!
